# Refactor: Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, filter

I have following code:

```
<DetailsBox title={t('catalogPage.componentDetails.specs.used')}>
  {component?.projects.map(project => {
    projectList?.map(name => {
      if (project.id === name.id) {
        return (
          <Typography variant="body2" gutterBottom classes={{}}>
            {`${name.name}`}
          </Typography>
        );
      }
    });
  })}
</DetailsBox>
```

and I got `Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function`, I know that it is caused by `return` in anonymous function, but how to refactor it?

Edit: The error is assigned to following line: `projectList?.map(name => {`

Comment: Mea culpa, already added the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is because you're only sometimes returning something from the `.map`; the resulting array will currently sometimes contain `undefined` elements interspersed with `Typography` components.

Use `.filter` instead, to filter out the IDs that don't match:

```
<DetailsBox title={t('catalogPage.componentDetails.specs.used')}>
  {component?.projects.map(project => (
    projectList
      ?.filter(name => project.id === name.id)
      ?.map(name => (
          <Typography variant="body2" gutterBottom classes={{}}>
            {`${name.name}`}
          </Typography>
      ))
  ))}
</DetailsBox>
```

Or, if there happens to be only a *single* match at most for every  pair, it would be more appropriate to create an object or Map of IDs to the `projects` items or to the `projectList` items - this will reduce the computational complexity to `O(n)` from `O(n ^ 2)`.

Comment: I think this is incorrect. You can return undefined, and it will be ignored by the renderer, also I believe you're missing a return statement still

Comment: @mbdavis - No missing `return`, note that the `map` callback is using the concise form.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder for the concise form you need parentheses, not curly brackets. Otherwise you just have a void function

Comment: @T.J.Crowder to clarify  - I'm talking about `component?.projects.map(project => {`

Comment: @mbdavis - Ah, I thought you meant the other one. Yes, that one is incorrect -- in the OP's question, and in the  above. To be fair, the question was about the inner one (or so it seemed to me -- re-reading, it's unclear), so it's easy enough to miss the *other* problem. Filtering vs. returning an array with `undefined`s comes down to style, and I'd certainly make it explicit if I did the latter.

Comment: You're right, OP's original code had a `{` when he needed a concise return `(` (or a `return`) that I didn't fix

Comment: Yeah - I mean it's not specified. But, I believe the style concern is not related to this question, as it wouldn't solve the error. IMO returning falsey values is pretty standard in react render functions to say to the parser "ignore this" - for example the patterns around short-circuiting when you're rendering to show/hide values on truthy/falsey conditions.

Comment: @mbdavis & CertainPerformance - The OP has now clarified which call the error relates to. It's the outer one.

Comment: @mbdavis - Indeed, though I had to double-check that it worked when the value was in an array. :-) I don't think I've ever seen anyone do that intentionally before, but I don't see a huge amount of React code except here.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder not going to lie I had to fire up VSCode to double check too!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well - now I stand corrected! I'm sure you'd need both solutions however - and I'm not sure why that's an error

Answer (score 2):

Your parent function isn't returning a value. So, you either need to use parentheses for an implicit return or an explicit return statement:

Implicit:

```
<DetailsBox title={t('catalogPage.componentDetails.specs.used')}>
  {component?.projects.map(project => (
    projectList?.map(name => {
      if (project.id === name.id) {
        return (
          <Typography variant="body2" gutterBottom classes={{}}>
            {`${name.name}`}
          </Typography>
        );
      }
    ));
  })}
</DetailsBox>
```

Explicit return:

```
<DetailsBox title={t('catalogPage.componentDetails.specs.used')}>
  {component?.projects.map(project => {
    return projectList?.map(name => {
        if (project.id === name.id) {
          return (
            <Typography variant="body2" gutterBottom classes={{}}>
              {`${name.name}`}
            </Typography>
          );
        }
    })
  })}
</DetailsBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<DetailsBox title={t('catalogPage.componentDetails.specs.used')}>
  {component?.projects.map(project => {
   return  projectList?.map(name => {
      if (project.id === name.id) {
        return (
          <Typography variant="body2" gutterBottom classes={{}}>
            {`${name.name}`}
          </Typography>
        );
      }
      return null
    });
    
  })}
</DetailsBox>
```

Comment: "Try this" is almost never a useful answer. Say *what* you did, and *why*.